# Specialized admin sees subset of objects, based on user

Tags: django-models, django-admin

I'm new to Django, so I may be completely off track here...

I've seen a lot of questions about being able to access the current user when an object is saved, but my problem is slightly different:  I'd like to use (a special subclass of) admin to show a user sets of objects, but only those object he or she has access to.

At the moment I am attempting to do this by creating a special "OpAdmin" app, whose sole purpose is to have this specialized admin.  An OpAdmin model looks something like this:

```
class OperatorAircraftManager(models.Manager):  
    def get_query_set(self, user):
        return mainapp.models.Aircraft.objects.filter(owner=user.employer)

class Aircraft(mainapp.models.Aircraft):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
    objects = OperatorAircraftManager()
```

But I am having a hard time getting my head around how I would pass the user information to `get_query_set`, or whether this is the wrong approach entirely (should I be doing something with `Groups` or `Permissions` instead?)   Again, this is not about saving the user info with a new Aircraft, or restricting who can change one, but about restricting who can *see* them in admin.   Any suggestions would be appreciated --- thanks.

Edit:  I should add that I have also seen a number of "get current user" packages for use with Django, but they all seem a bit hacky (looking on the current call stack for example), so I've been reluctant to go that route.  If there is an accepted way to cache some shared information about the request context, that would be good to know...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "only those object he or she has access to". But if you want to limit all objects to their respective owners in the admin, this is how you do that:

```
def queryset(self, request):
    """Limit Pages to those that belong to the request's user."""
    qs = super(PageAdmin, self).queryset(request)
    return qs.filter(owner=request.user)
```

Comment: So this is what confuses me:  the normal API signature for queryset functions does not take a `request` parameter.  How does adding one magically cause the request object to be passed in? (The "access to" functionality is the semantics of my app --- I left out the details because they are unimportant.)

Comment: `queryset()` is an Admin method. Not Model.

Comment: Ignore the above... Clarifying:   I'm still confused because this only creates a function definition.  Something still has to _call_ that function, and supply the parameter.  That something has to be somewhere inside of admin (the part of admin that populates the lists of objects).  I cannot figure out where/how to do that part.

Comment: Thank you @dan-klasson!   I get it now.   ModelAdmin.queryset() is a different API call.  Thanks.